# Sending Image via Intent.ACTION_SENDTO

Tags: android, android-intent

I tried to send gif file with `Intent.Action_SEND` and it works perfectly here:

```
Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Log.d(TAG, " PATH : "+ fileUri.toString());
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
shareIntent.setType("*/*");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
Intent new_intent = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via");
new_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(new_intent);
```

Now I wish to do the same but with `Intent.ACTION_SENDTO` to send it to current windows. For example I am writing to my friend on hangouts and I wish to share my gif without having to pick application and user that will get it.

As far as I understand code would be similar something like this:

```
Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Log.d(TAG, " PATH : "+ fileUri.toString());
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
shareIntent.setType("*/*");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Thanks in advance I am really stuck on this one.

Comment: "Now I wish to do the same but with Intent.ACTION_SENDTO to send it to current windows" -- `ACTION_SENDTO` has nothing to do with "current windows".

Comment: Thanks! I guess I was mislead by the word "TO", is there a way to use Intent.ACTIONSEND without that nasty popUp since I am in chat window with friend so obviously I would share that file with him.

Comment: You need to find an API native to the chat app and try using it.